# Bash sed command replace with output of a command

Tags: git, bash, macos, shell, sed

I'm working on one of my first bash scripts on mac. My goal is to *read the name of my git branch*, save it into the terminal variable `PR_TITLE` and then finally replace the placeholder `pull_request_name` with the variable `$PR_TITLE` using `sed -i`.

Below are the terminal commands I am running. Setting the variable is working fine but I am unable to replace the placeholder with the variable. Currently bash outputs the following when I run my sed command. `-bash: feature/issues-5-6: No such file or directory`

```
PR_TITLE=$( git branch | grep \* | tr -d '*' )

sed -i '' "s/\pull_request_name/$($PR_TITLE)/" /Users/$USER/Desktop/PR_File.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use inside quote `"` bash command substitution command `$(command)`. To avoid this you need quote first `$`.

```
sed -i '' "s/\pull_request_name/\$($PR_TITLE)/" /Users/$USER/Desktop/PR_File.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Are you saying my command needs a change to the quotation marks like so `sed -i '' "s/\pull_request_name/"$($PR_TITLE)"/" /Users/$USER/Desktop/PR_File.txt`

Comment: The command you posted gives a substitute error `sed: 1: "s/\pull_request_name/$( ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'i'`

Comment: Probably I was mistaken. Try `sed -i '' "s/\pull_request_name/$PR_TITLE/" /Users/$USER/Desktop/PR_File.txt` and check out if it what you need.

Comment: your solution works. I found the issue. The variable `$PR_TITLE` value is _feature/issues-5-6_ I need to figure out how to escape the forward slash so it will write ti to the file

Comment: Ah ok. Try this `sed -i '' "s@\pull_request_name@$PR_TITLE@" /Users/$USER/Desktop/PR_File.txt`. You can use in command `s///` as esc charaster any char.